# Discord.js Bot embed message isn't showing bot avatar

Tags: javascript, embed, discord, discord.js, avatar

Hi I'm creating my own discord bot and I want to use the command `!botinfo`

When I use that command it has to show a embed message in my channel.
So far everything works expect it doesn't show my Discord bot his avatar.
Can anyone help me out?

```
if (command === `${prefix}botinfo`) {

    var botIcon = new bot.user.displayAvatarURL;

    var botEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription("Discord bot info")
        .setColor(0xF1C40F)
        .setThumbnail(botIcon)
        .addField("Bot name", bot.user.username);

return message.channel.send(botEmbed);
```

The error I get is -> `bot.user.displayAvatarURL is not a constructor`

Answer (score 4):

Do not use the `new` keyword when accessing methods (or properties).  You only use that to create new object instances.

```
var botIcon = bot.user.displayAvatarURL();
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution

````
if (command === `${prefix}botinfo`) {


        var botEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription("Bot Info")
            .setColor(0xF1C40F)
            .setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .addField("Bot name", bot.user.username, true)
            .addField("Version", version, true)
            .addField("Creator", creator)

            return message.channel.send(botEmbed);
    }```
````